# passing parameters <button type="button"> from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have such a code view:

```
<section>
    @foreach (var request in request_list)
    {
        <div style="display:inline">
            <button class="checkbox checked" type="button" >@request.Message</button>
        </div>
    }
</section>
```

and javascript:

```
$('.checkbox').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('checked');
});
```

How do I get the controller if the class of the button checked?

Comment: What do you mean _How do I get the controller_? What is it that you trying to do when you click the button?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `$.ajax`
you find more information on http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/